# Restrict webpage access with controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am currently working on a small, simple project. I have a list of users stored in a database like so:

```
Id (uniqueidentifier primary key), FirstName(varchar), LastName(varchar), PhoneNo(varchar), DomainAC(varchar)
```

I am using ASP.net MVC to create a page with the following simple functionality :

[image: http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/7285/difq.png]

Display all users details on the page - which I have done by using the following code generated by the view I created using the Index function of the ModelController hooked to my database :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Proj.Models.Employee>>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>
    </p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName) %>
            </th>
            <th>
                <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneNo) %>
            </th>
            <th>
                <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DomainAC) %>
            </th>
            <th>
                <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName) %>
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneNo) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DomainAC) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) %> |
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) %> |
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id }) %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <% } %>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This renders a bare HTML page, showing all users in a bare table. There are create/edit/delete buttons; but they do nothing.

What I would like to do is simply, for each row

```
if(DomainAC == currently logged in Domain AC || currently logged in Domain AC is admin)
    Allow user to edit/update details.
```

After some investigation I think I need to create a custom controller that reads who you are currently logged in as and shows the edit button when the row returned by the DB == the currently logged in user.

```
    [Authorize(Users = @Context.User.Identity.Name)]
    public ActionResult CurrentUser()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "You are the logged in user";

        return View();
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = @"DOMAIN\Administrators")]

    public ActionResult Admins()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your are admin.";

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: @banging How can I link the components above together to create the effect I wish, displaying all of the users but only allowing them to edit their own profiles? Are the components I have attempted to use above even correct? If not, what is better and how can that be used to achieve the desired effect? My apologies for not being clear in my post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a custom attribute like this:

```
public class DomainACUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private UnitOfWork _unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var isAuthorized = false;
        var username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        // Some code to find the user in the database...
        var user = _unitOfWork.EmployeeRepository.Find(username);
        if(user != null)
        {
           isAuthorized = true;
        }


        return isAuthorized;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {            
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        if (AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
        {
            SetCachePolicy(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
           // If not authorized, open the Unauthorized page... 
           filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Unauthorized" };
        }
    }

    protected void SetCachePolicy(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // ** IMPORTANT **
        // Since we're performing authorization at the action level, 
        // the authorization code runs after the output caching module. 
        // In the worst case this could allow an authorized user 
        // to cause the page to be cached, then an unauthorized user would later 
        // be served the cached page. We work around this by telling proxies not to 
        // cache the sensitive page, then we hook our custom authorization code into 
        // the caching mechanism so that we have the final say on whether a page 
        // should be served from the cache.
        HttpCachePolicyBase cachePolicy = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
        cachePolicy.SetProxyMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0));
        cachePolicy.AddValidationCallback(CacheValidationHandler, null /* data */);
    }

    public void CacheValidationHandler(HttpContext context,
                                        object data,
                                        ref HttpValidationStatus validationStatus)
    {
        validationStatus = OnCacheAuthorization(new HttpContextWrapper(context));
    }
}
```

Then, you can use this attribute for your Controller Actions like this:

```
[DomainACUser]
public ActionResults Edit()
{
  // Some code...
}
```

You can create a separate custom attribute for Admins only. And, use it for the actions that are supposed to be accessed by Admins only.

If you want to hide the Edit and Delete links from people who are not supposed to have access to them, you can check the user privilege in your controller, and pass the information to your View in ViewData like this:

```
// Code to check if the user is admin...
if (User is Admin)
{
   ViewData["DisplayEdit"] = true;
}
```

And, in your View:

```
<td>
    <% if ((bool)ViewData["DisplayEdit"]) { %>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) %> 
    <% } %>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is just putting conditionals directly into your view, and also manually checking for permission on your controller:

```
<td>
    <% if (User.IsInRole("Administrators") || User.Identity.Name == item.DomainAC) { %>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) %> |
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) %> |
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id }) %>
    <% } %>
</td>

public ActionResult Edit(int id) {
    var user = GetUserById(id);
    if (!User.IsInRole("Administrators") && User.Identity.Name != user.DomainAC) {
        // unauthorized
    }

    // authorized - continue
}
```

Comment: ... or add a boolean property `Editable` to the model, which will be true if (User.IsInRole("Administrators") || User.Identity.Name == item.DomainAC).  Moves the authorization business logic out of the View, which is cleaner and more easily testable.  You shouldn't need to change your View if the business requirement changes tomorrow so that a manager can edit his subordinates.